# Error :MultiThreaded client-server application

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets

I am developing MultiThreaded client-server application in VB.net, where multiple client connect to the one server,there are also process in the server side that open the XML file and write some Data.
  But after 1 hrs i got the following Error:

> *"File is used by another proccess."*

Is there any suggestion from your side,for above issue.
Please check my below code for reading XML

```
Public Function ISRecordExitsinXML(ByVal pFilepath As String, ByVal pClientIP As String, ByVal pMacAddress As String)
    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = Nothing
    Dim xmlPupilNode As XmlNode = Nothing
    Dim xmlAgeNode As XmlNode = Nothing
    Try

        Dim FileName As String = pFilepath
        ISRecordExitsinXML = Nothing

        xmlDoc = New XmlDocument
        xmlDoc.Load(FileName)
        xmlPupilNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//RFIDReader[HostIPAddress = '" & pClientIP.Trim & "' and MacAddress = '" & pMacAddress & "' and Status=1]  ")

        If Not xmlPupilNode Is Nothing Then
            xmlAgeNode = xmlPupilNode.SelectSingleNode("RegDateTime")
            If Not xmlAgeNode Is Nothing Then
                xmlAgeNode.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString()
                xmlDoc.Save(FileName)
                ISRecordExitsinXML = True
            End If
        Else
            ISRecordExitsinXML = False
        End If
        xmlDoc = Nothing
        xmlPupilNode = Nothing
        xmlAgeNode = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        xmlDoc = Nothing
        xmlPupilNode = Nothing
        xmlAgeNode = Nothing
        ISRecordExitsinXML = False
        ErrorLog.WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message.ToString(), "HSRV-A9", "ErrorLog.Log")
    Finally
        xmlDoc = Nothing
        xmlPupilNode = Nothing
        xmlAgeNode = Nothing
    End Try
    Return ISRecordExitsinXML
End Function
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I would look into thread safety and making certain areas of your application "thread-safe"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163929.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f857xew0(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (as I'm sure you are aware!) is that when the file is open by one process, it cannot be opened by another.
Is there a possibility of using an alternative medium to receive the data, such as a database? You could then export the data from the database to an XML file in one hit, avoiding the conflict altogether.

Comment: Thanks for Reply,but i have to use XML file only that is the requirement.

Comment: OK, no probs. Is it possible to implement a wait feature - if the file is in use then pause for a second or two to allow it time to be written to and close and try again?

Answer (score 0):

you may not be closing file after writing process is over, so it will be inaccessible by other  threads

Comment: Thanks for replay,I Have a 2 Windows Client Service which running on 2 different Desktops and server is on WAN which also have the Windows Service,so every after 30 sec interval my client services connect to Server and update XML File,till 1 Hour its working fine but after that i getting above Error.